# OpenCV, cherrypy, display image in browser using key press

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, cherrypy

I know this will be a bit weird, and please, bear with me for asking this stupid question, and also, a bad coding style, because, I know that one must not declare everything in a constructor and use them also.

My goal here is to upload a static image content. I am using the libraries `opencv` and `'cherrypy'`

While, the opencv part will be used to show the images, the reason for using cherrypy is to upload the image in browser, and using the `waitKey(0)`, I want to refresh these images.

Problem is that this is not working, and I know, that the design is poor.

I am posting this because, I am out of solutions now, and would like to get some help in this, even a minor tip is also fine, I will correct the code myself.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
import cherrypy
import cv2
import base64


class Img(object):

    def __init__(self):


        self.plat = sys.platform

        if self.plat == 'win32':

            self.file_dir = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\fruit\\"

        elif self.plat == 'linux2':

            self.file_dir = "/host/Users/user/Desktop/fruit/"

        print self.plat
        print self.file_dir

        self.img   = cv2.imread(self.file_dir + "orange.jpg")



    @cherrypy.expose

    def index(self):


        self.k = cv2.waitKey(0)

        if self.k == 'w':

            # self.img   = cv2.imread(self.file_dir + "orange.jpg")

            _, data     =  cv2.imencode('.jpeg', self.img)

            jpeg_base64 = base64.b64encode(data.tostring())

            return """
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Fruit Nutritional Information</title>
            </head>
            <html>
            <body>
            <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,%s' height = 640 width = 1200 />
            </body>
            </html
            """ % (jpeg_base64)

        elif self.k == ord('q'):
            sys.exit()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1', 'server.socket_port':8080 })
    cherrypy.quickstart(Img())
```

Comment: cv2.waitKey(0) waits for a keypress in a highgui window, like with cv2.imshow(). since you don't use imshow, there'S no window, and waitKey() has no effect at all

Comment: Thanks. Ok, so this means that there is no ways to display static content in browser and handling the event via keyboard?

Comment: @vamosrafa yes, this is not how it works. There different ways to interact with user, one is via console (keyboard input, text output), other is via HTTP (input - HTTP request, output - html in HTTP response). You can't mix them. If you want your app to react to keyboard from browser you need to use client side Javascript code.

Comment: Andrey: Thanks, even I was thinking the same. So do I need to use AJAX or Jquery. This is very basic thing, only static images, so I don't want to make it complex. Besides, I want to have a fast application, with low response time. Any pointer towards this, to user javascript, because, I have not used it yet.

Comment: @vamosrafa don't worry about fast application. start with making *working* one first. It looks like you have very little understanding how web development works in general. Regarding python (server-side) I recommend flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/) regarding JS, just google for JS and jQuery tutorials, there are lots of good ones.

Comment: This is my first project in which I am doing web development actually :)/

Answer (score 0):

You could serve a JavaScript file that accepts keyboard input:
[serving static content with CherryPy](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-6-what-about-my-javascripts-css-and-images)
Or just put the JavaScript code within script tags in your HTML code.

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? Link can expire in any moment, so it is better to have whole description of your solution here. Thank you!